# How can I use regex to search inside sentence -not a case sensitive

Tags: python, regex, list, search

I'm a newbie to Regular expression in Python :
I have a list that i want to search if it's contain a employee name.

The employee name can be :

- it can be at the beginning followed by space.
- followed by Â®
- OR followed by space
- OR Can be at the end and space before it
- not a case sensitive

---

```
ListSentence = ["SteveÂ®", "steveHotel", "Rob spring", "Car Daniel", "CarDaniel","Done daniel"]
ListEmployee = ["Steve", "Rob", "daniel"]
```

---

The output from the `ListSentence` is:

```
["SteveÂ®", "Rob spring", "Car Daniel", "Done daniel"]
```

Comment: Really `Â®`? Is that a unicode glitch?

Comment: Can you make this more clear?  `Rob spring` is not followed by a space and is not "at the end and space before it".

Comment: yes it's. it's a commerce sign,

Comment: my bad I didn't add it to the condition list, I edit my question, it can be at the beginning followed by space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to check for all of those scenarios.  I think all you need to do is check for word breaks.

You can join the ListEmployee list with `|` to make an either or regex (also, lowercase it for case-insensitivity), surrounded by `\b` for word breaks, and that should work:

```
regex = '|'.join(ListEmployee).lower()
import re
[l for l in ListSentence if re.search(r'\b(%s)\b' % regex, l.lower())]
```

Should output:

```
['Steve\xb6\xa9', 'Rob spring', 'Car Daniel', 'Done daniel']
```

Comment: Good.  I think @Ben Lerner has a point too though.  You probably don't need regex at all.  I'm going to add to my solution a way to do it without regex.

Comment: Be aware the `\b` symbols here will allow strings like `dog&daniel#moretext` which would fail the criteria

Comment: @Denomales Correct.  However, I figured this would be a more practical solution.  I just can't imagine why someone would employ someone named `dog%daniel#moretext`.

Comment: Thank you @Denomales for pointing this out, I didn't not see it, it's not the employee name that is funny but the person who enter those names didn't enter them correctly or when the data is moving around btw databases it get some times funny.

Comment: Your right it's a stretch, however imagine someone with a hyphenated last name `Ray-Steven`, this could be matched with `\bRay\b` or `\bSteven\b`

Answer (score 6):

First take all your employee names and join them with a `|` character and wrap the string so it looks like:

`(?:^|\s)((?:Steve|Rob|Daniel)(?:Â®)?)(?=\s|$)`
[image]

By first joining all the names together you avoid the performance overhead of using a nested set of for next loops.

I don't know python well enough to offer a python example, however in powershell I'd write it like this

```
[array]$names = @("Steve", "Rob", "daniel")
[array]$ListSentence = @("SteveÂ®", "steveHotel", "Rob spring", "Car Daniel", "CarDaniel","Done daniel")

# build the regex, and insert the names as a "|" delimited string
$Regex = "(?:^|\s)((?:" + $($names -join "|") + ")(?:Â®)?)(?=\s|$)" 

# use case insensitive match to find any matching array values
$ListSentence -imatch $Regex
```

Yields

```
SteveÂ®
Rob spring
Car Daniel
Done daniel
```

Comment: Looks great! can you please give me an example of how to use your above code?Thank you very much!!

Comment: Nice graph, what did you use to make it?

Comment: Thank you very much @Denomales for the great explanation and the graph helped me a lot to understand your method!! Tank you again!!

Comment: I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: I have a question. Does making the regex non-capturing e.g. `(?:Steve|Rob|Daniel)` instead of just `(Steve|Rob|Daniel)` improve the performance?

Comment: Yes a non capturing group with `(?:`...`)` does improve performance. And in this case it allows all names to end with the requested `Â®`.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use regular expressions?  I'd generally recommend avoiding them in Python - you can use string methods instead.

For example:

```
def string_has_employee_name_in_it(test_string):
    test_string = test_string.lower() # case insensitive
    for name in ListEmployee:
        name = name.lower()
        if name == test_string:
            return True
        elif name + 'Â®' == test_string:
            return True
        elif test_string.endswith(' ' + name):
            return True
        elif test_string.startswith(name + ' '):
            return True
        elif (' ' + name + ' ') in test_string:
            return True
    return False   

final_list = []
for string in ListSentence:
    if string_has_employee_name_in_it(string):
        final_list.append(string)
```

final_list is the list you want.  This is longer than a regex, but it's also a lot easier to parse and maintain.  You can make it a lot shorter in various ways (e.g. combining the tests in the function, and using a list comprehension instead of a loop), but as you're starting out with Python it's a good idea to be clear with what's going on.

Comment: You're probably correct, in that OP doesn't need to use regex.  I don't think it needs to be this complicated either.  I think you can just strip those unicode characters and check `if name in list`.

Comment: @bozdoz, very good one! remove the unicode characters and do a straight check!! I love it!! I learned a lot this evening! thank you all guys!!!!

Comment: 'if name in list' gives a false positive on 'CarDaniel', which OP doesn't want. removing the unicode can throw in some false positives too - e.g. if it's in the middle of the word.
in practice that might not be a concern, in which case stripping the unicode is ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for strings containing a space, as your example indicates, it should be something like this:

```
[i for i in ListSentence if i.endswith('Â®') or (' ' in i)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response!! it to be checked with the employee List, so only the employee listed are searched for.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
import re

ListSentence = ["SteveÂ®", "steveHotel", "Rob spring", "Car Daniel", "CarDaniel","Done daniel"]
ListEmployee = ["Steve", "Rob", "daniel"]


def findEmployees(employees, sentence):
    retval = []
    for employee in employees:
        expr = re.compile(r'(^%(employee)s(Â®)?(\s|$))|((^|\s)%(employee)s(Â®)?(\s|$))|((^|\s)%(employee)s(Â®)?$)' 
            % {'employee': employee}, 
          re.IGNORECASE)
        for part in sentence:
            if expr.search(part):
                retval.append(part)
    return retval



findEmployees(ListEmployee, ListSentence)

>> Returns ['Steve\xc3\x82\xc2\xae', 'Rob spring', 'Car Daniel', 'Done daniel']
```

Comment: great call for `re.compile()` function!! Thank you Orlenko!!

Comment: Beware that @Denomales's comment about `\b` also applies to \W. I'll update my regex with a more robust one in a minute.

Comment: Updated. The word boundaries should work properly in this one.